# Two から in the same sentence

Tags: meaning, particle-から

I'm playing a game that talks about the story of [Princess Kaguya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Bamboo_Cutter) in the following way. I think I got the general gist of it, but I found the second sentence in particular to be perplexing. I think the first から is use to say she came from the moon, but I'm not sure what meaning of the second から is.

> 確かにかぐや姫は月を見ては泣いていました。。。

Princess Kaguya did indeed cry when looking upon the moon.

> でも、それはかぐやが月**から**来た**から**じゃないの。。。

But, she wasn't crying because she came(??) from the moon

> 月はツクヨミの象徴で、実はかぐやは前世を懐かしんで泣いてたの。。。

Because the moon is the symbol of Tsukuyomi, Kaguya was in truth yearning for her previous life.

> つまり彼女を迎えに来た月の住の正体はツクヨミ。。。

In other words, the moon resident who came to take her back was Tsukuyomi.

Comment: There's "because" in your translation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> でも、それはかぐやが月から来たからじゃないの。。。
>
> However, it was not because she had come from the moon.

The first "から" is simply "from" and the second is "since" or "because".

The tricky part here is じゃない after the 2nd から which you may not have seen. Here is means "It wasn't because of ..."

This sentence is talking about the one previous to it. And the real reason for the first sentence (her crying) is described in the 3rd and 4th sentences.

Comment: Well I felt that sentence was just strange because isn't it seems to contradict the 3rd/4th sentence, which say she was crying because she was homesick. But surely this one just says she wasn't crying because she left the moon.

Comment: he wasn't crying because not because she came from the moon, but because of her previous life.

Comment: BUt aren't those the same? Her previous life was life on the moon..

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the first is "from" and the second is "since."

```
でも、それはかぐやが月から来たからじゃないの。。。

However, wasn't that since she came from the moon...?
```

Not super confident in my answer, but that's how I would understand it if I didn't think too hard.

Comment: The sentence is a statement, and not a question.