# What does 待ってるから mean?

Tags: word-choice

I know what both words mean but I'm not sure what's implied here.

Context: I'm reading this from the manga, 五等分の花嫁。A girl said this to a boy after she asked him to dance at a campfire with him, 私と踊ってくれませんか？待ってるから.  Also, the campfire would be the next day and this was the first encounter between the two people. They don't have an established relationship.

I think the subject of the sentence is the speaker and she's saying I'll be waiting. What's the から doing here though? The unsaid subject is "I" (the speaker) not something like 今. Are we also supposed to assume that から means the current place in time in this situation? "I'll be waiting from now on."

I feel there's a simple explanation for this but I think I'm just missing something obvious here. Or perhaps I'm right but I find that unlikely. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Post the context, it's always helpful.

Comment: Please let me know if what I posted now is sufficient. I always seem underestimate what can be inferred from a single sentence with minimal context.

Comment: Very nicely done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you already know the [reason kara](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40069/16104), which is the one being used here... basically meaning "because".

There could be a lot of things implied here that are not being said, but with the context in hand I would guess the following.

> (私は)待ってるから(、来てね。) - **Hey come, I'm waiting! (Implying that because she is waiting for him, he should go and dance with her already.)**

**Edit:**

With the context you provided I would translate it as:

> 1 - 私と踊ってくれませんか？...(私は)待ってるから(踊ってくれ）- **Won't you dance with me? ... I'll be waiting for you (and because of that, come and dance with me).**

or

> 2 - 私と踊ってくれませんか？...(私は)待ってるから(答えてくれ）- **Won't you dance with me? I'm waiting, answer me! (So because i'm waiting answer me, don't leave me hanging)**

Comment: Hey, I added a bit more context in my question. Please let me know if this is sufficient and if your answer would change at all

Comment: @UCProgrammer I have only watched the anime, so if my memory isn't failing me, I'd say the "1" is more likely to be the best translation.

Comment: Yea I just watched the part of the anime where she says this. 1 seems to fit